# Moving uncommited changes between git branch

Tags: git

I have changes on Master,
changed to an existing branch - 
checkout ABC

The change doesn't appear in 
git status

How do I pull them to the other branch?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way I move uncommitted changes is to create a new branch, so from master `$ git branch my-new-branch` then checkout the new branch `$ git checkout my-new-branch`, then commit the changes. To move the changes to ABC, you would checkout ABC then rebase `$ git rebase my-new-branch`.

You can also use the stash command, so from master `$ git stash` then checkout ABC then `$ git stash pop` and your changes should be ready to commit.